# Square API - The payment total does not match the order total. It does

Tags: api, payment, orders, square

First off, I created an order and doing an order search, the string below shows the order details from the response.

Next, I used the API Explorers for Payments->CreatePayment:
https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/payments-api/create-payment/explorer

I put in my sandbox Access Token at the top.

As for the other info I entered, please refer to the Request String:

```
curl https://connect.squareup.com/v2/payments \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Square-Version: 2020-01-22' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}' \
  -d '{
    "source_id": "cnon:CBASEBbXLsTfPIy04J18kMjfbRo",
    "idempotency_key": "5e42534d06257",
    "location_id": "DWK1VQ391ZARF",
    "order_id": "fQZM8ekWkcAo7fRRBvUj2G2pY5EZY",
    "amount_money": {
      "amount": 3649,
      "currency": "USD"
    }
  }'
```

Here is the Order Details:

```
{
      "id": "fQZM8ekWkcAo7fRRBvUj2G2pY5EZY",
      "location_id": "DWK1VQ391ZARF",
      "line_items": [
        {
          "uid": "iLVwmNInonSV2Twc9G84fD",
          "catalog_object_id": "B57CGCIAGUTLBQMAMEEI5WBC",
          "quantity": "1",
          "name": "Athletic Heather Pullover Hooded Sweatshirt",
          "variation_name": "X-Large",
          "base_price_money": {
            "amount": 2699,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "taxes": [
            {
              "uid": "f9euLpXOOEWKd2bV7AgOdD",
              "name": "Sales Tax",
              "percentage": "9.0",
              "type": "ADDITIVE",
              "applied_money": {
                "amount": 243,
                "currency": "USD"
              },
              "scope": "LINE_ITEM"
            }
          ],
          "gross_sales_money": {
            "amount": 2699,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_tax_money": {
            "amount": 243,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_discount_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_money": {
            "amount": 2942,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "variation_total_price_money": {
            "amount": 2699,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "applied_taxes": [
            {
              "uid": "f9euLpXOOEWKd2bV7AgOdD",
              "tax_uid": "f9euLpXOOEWKd2bV7AgOdD",
              "applied_money": {
                "amount": 243,
                "currency": "USD"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "uid": "dQS0tXEW46ERhQlLdPAxgC",
          "catalog_object_id": "PY7V64HVFKSE6O7SW6RBQZ7U",
          "quantity": "1",
          "name": "2nd Amendment",
          "variation_name": "Small Print",
          "base_price_money": {
            "amount": 300,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "taxes": [
            {
              "uid": "RAD93NhnUa9E6XBy7NYWG",
              "name": "Sales Tax",
              "percentage": "9.0",
              "type": "ADDITIVE",
              "applied_money": {
                "amount": 27,
                "currency": "USD"
              },
              "scope": "LINE_ITEM"
            }
          ],
          "gross_sales_money": {
            "amount": 300,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_tax_money": {
            "amount": 27,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_discount_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_money": {
            "amount": 327,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "variation_total_price_money": {
            "amount": 300,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "applied_taxes": [
            {
              "uid": "RAD93NhnUa9E6XBy7NYWG",
              "tax_uid": "RAD93NhnUa9E6XBy7NYWG",
              "applied_money": {
                "amount": 27,
                "currency": "USD"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "uid": "mIae9M46tMvTCpzgNvyNW",
          "catalog_object_id": "Q4OPKIJ2BMG5LY35SUMHFG7S",
          "quantity": "1",
          "name": "2nd Amendment",
          "variation_name": "Large",
          "base_price_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "taxes": [
            {
              "uid": "IFLJKtYmIiEvXTLZ5FLaJD",
              "name": "Sales Tax",
              "percentage": "9.0",
              "type": "ADDITIVE",
              "applied_money": {
                "amount": 0,
                "currency": "USD"
              },
              "scope": "LINE_ITEM"
            }
          ],
          "gross_sales_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_tax_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_discount_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "variation_total_price_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "applied_taxes": [
            {
              "uid": "IFLJKtYmIiEvXTLZ5FLaJD",
              "tax_uid": "IFLJKtYmIiEvXTLZ5FLaJD",
              "applied_money": {
                "amount": 0,
                "currency": "USD"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "uid": "w3HK68X6MEpXHIxQDyTZ5",
          "quantity": "1",
          "name": "Shipping",
          "base_price_money": {
            "amount": 380,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "gross_sales_money": {
            "amount": 380,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_tax_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_discount_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_money": {
            "amount": 380,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "variation_total_price_money": {
            "amount": 380,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        }
      ],
      "taxes": [
        {
          "uid": "IFLJKtYmIiEvXTLZ5FLaJD",
          "name": "Sales Tax",
          "percentage": "9.0",
          "type": "ADDITIVE",
          "applied_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "scope": "LINE_ITEM"
        },
        {
          "uid": "RAD93NhnUa9E6XBy7NYWG",
          "name": "Sales Tax",
          "percentage": "9.0",
          "type": "ADDITIVE",
          "applied_money": {
            "amount": 27,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "scope": "LINE_ITEM"
        },
        {
          "uid": "f9euLpXOOEWKd2bV7AgOdD",
          "name": "Sales Tax",
          "percentage": "9.0",
          "type": "ADDITIVE",
          "applied_money": {
            "amount": 243,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "scope": "LINE_ITEM"
        }
      ],
      "created_at": "2020-02-11T07:46:54.962Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-02-11T07:46:54.962Z",
      "state": "OPEN",
      "version": 1,
      "total_tax_money": {
        "amount": 270,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "total_discount_money": {
        "amount": 0,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "total_tip_money": {
        "amount": 0,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "total_money": {
        "amount": 3649,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "total_service_charge_money": {
        "amount": 0,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "net_amounts": {
        "total_money": {
          "amount": 3649,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "tax_money": {
          "amount": 270,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "discount_money": {
          "amount": 0,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "tip_money": {
          "amount": 0,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "service_charge_money": {
          "amount": 0,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      },
      "source": {
        "name": "Sandbox for sq0idp-0WcmbRcdTbsMGg5UjGvifQ"
      }
    }
```

Please note the order_id and location_id both match what's in the order details. What also matches is the amount entered in the create payment request and the total_money in the order details: 3649.

So then why do I get the following response for the Create Payment request?

```
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 136
content-type: application/json
date: Tue, 11 Feb 2020 07:48:48 GMT
square-version: 2020-01-22


{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "BAD_REQUEST",
      "detail": "The payment total does not match the order total.",
      "category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using Square API v2.

Comment: First and foremost, please revoke your access token ASAP. You just shared it with the world, which means anyone would be able to access your account via the APIs. Will follow up once I take a look at the actual problem.

Comment: Looks like you created the order in sandbox, but trying to create the payment in production. Seems like the error could be better, I'll pass this along to our Orders team. However, you must use the same environment for both calls.

Comment: It's a fake access token

Comment: Also, for both environments, access token was entered the same. and Sandbox was selected on both.

Comment: @sjosey Turns out it was giving me that error, but when I go back and do a batchRetrieveOrders on the Order ID, it shows the payment information. So it successfully added the payment, but still gave me the error.

Comment: Strange. Are you able to replicate this issue? When I looked yesterday the order payment was definitely being called in production instead of sandbox. If you are able to replicate it, can you please share the `order_id` here?

Comment: Turned out it was giving me the error when I update an order with a new version number, but I never changed the total. I only added shipping address.